# MongoDB Panache queries not returning any result

Tags: mongodb, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I am having problems with querying with MongoDB.
Whenever I try to find by ID or any other field, I always get zero results back.
And I am also having trouble to use the 'like' operator.

What I wanna query is the titles of the books in a case insensitive way. And I know you can do it like this in MongoDB:

```
{title: {$regex: /^query.*/i}}
```

And I try to do this with Panache but I can't get it working:

```
Book.find("title like ?1", "/^" + query + ".*/i");
```

I see the following line on the console getting printed out:
    {'title':{'$regex':'/^Harr.*/i'}}

I've also tried it with a Document, but also not success:

```
Document query = new Document();
query.put("title", "$regex: /^" + query + ".*/i");
Book.find(query);
```

And I get zero results back.

And here is my Book class:

```
public class Book extends PanacheMongoEntity {

@NotEmpty
public String title;

@NotEmpty
public String isbn;

@NotEmpty
public String author;

@Min(1)
@NotNull
public BigDecimal price;
}
```

And here is my BookResource:

```
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/books")
public class BookResource {

@GET
public List<Book> get() {
    return Book.listAll();
}

@GET
@Path("/{id}")
public Book find(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    return (Book) Book.findByIdOptional(id).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("Book not found"));
}

@GET
@Path("/title/{title}")
public PanacheQuery<PanacheMongoEntityBase> findByTitle(@PathParam("title") String title) {
    Document query = new Document();
//        query.put("title", new BasicDBObject("$regex", ).append("$options", "i"));

    return Optional.ofNullable(Book.find("title like ?1", format("/^%s.*/i", title))).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("Book not found"));
}

@POST
public void add(@Valid Book book) {
    Book.persist(book);
}

@PUT
@Path("/{id}")
public void update(@PathParam("id") String id, @Valid Book book) {
    Book result = Book.findById(id);
    if (result != null) {
        result.author = book.author;
        result.isbn = book.isbn;
        result.price = book.price;
        result.title = book.title;

        Book.update(result);
    }
}
}
```

When I do a findAll via curl I get this:

```
[
{
"id": "5eb9475b8a4314145246cc10",
"author": "J.K. Rowling",
"isbn": "12345678",
"price": 24.95,
"title": "Harry Potter 1"
},
{
"id": "5eb95a758a4314145246cc25",
"isbn": "456",
"price": 0,
"title": "Java for dummies"
},
{
"id": "5eb95b1a8a4314145246cc27",
"author": "steven king",
"isbn": "456",
"price": 10,
"title": "IT"
}
]
```

And when I try to find a Book by id, I also get zero results:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/books/5eb9475b8a4314145246cc10" -H "accept: application/json"

=> 404 No Books found.
```

The only operation that seems to work is the POST (persist), the rest of the methods don't return anything.

I have the following setup:

- MongoDB 4.2 running via Docker
- Quarkus 1.4.2
- JDK 11

And here is my application.properties:

```
quarkus.mongodb.connection-string=mongodb://localhost:27017
quarkus.mongodb.database=books
quarkus.log.category."io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.runtime".level=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 1):

The following piece of code is wrong:

```
@GET
@Path("/title/{title}")
public PanacheQuery<PanacheMongoEntityBase> findByTitle(@PathParam("title") String title) {
    Document query = new Document();
    //query.put("title", new BasicDBObject("$regex", ).append("$options", "i"));

    return Optional.ofNullable(Book.find("title like ?1", format("/^%s.*/i", title))).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("Book not found"));
}
```

`Book.find()` return a `PanacheQuery`, you need to call one of the terminator operations of the query to get the results: list/stream/findFirst/findOne.

I would suggest implementing it like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/title/{title}")
public List<Book> findByTitle(@PathParam("title") String title) {
    return Book.list("title like ?1", format("/^%s.*/i", title)));
}
```

`list()` is a shortcut for `find().list()`, if you don't need pagination or other things that are available on the `PanacheQuery` interface you can directly use `list()`.

Comment: OK, I've changed it into list()...and I see the following line on the console:
[io.qua.mon.pan.run.MongoOperations].... {'title':{'$regex':'/^harr.*/i'}}

And I see still no any result.

Comment: OK, I see what's happening...the correct query should be without quotes !
If I do this, then it works: return Book.list(format("{title: {$regex: /.*%s.*/i}}", title));

And this is a bug in Panache, it places quotes on the property (title) and on it's value.

Another question: why is findById also not returning any result when I just search by ObjectId ?

Comment: Indead, only String pattern is currently supported in Quarkus not JavaScript pattern (the one started with / and ending with / and possibly some options).
Support of JavaScript pattern is currently on discussion here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/9219

Comment: If this acts similar to the mongo java driver, you might get to the correct result by using "=" and Pattern.compile(<yourregex>) as the query. Might be worth a try.